# Simple Curl script returning no data when using variable to call the function

Tags: php, curl

Here is my code :

```
function get_data($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 15;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, random_user_agent());
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}

//Grab HTML
$urllist = fopen("links.txt", "r+");
for ($j = 0; $j <= 50; $j++)
{
$post = rtrim(fgets($urllist));
echo $post;
$html = get_data($post);
echo $html;
```

Problem : when I use `get_data("http://url.com")` I get the right data in html. But when I pass the url using a variable, `$html` returns nothing.

$post holds the right url as I checked it. Isnt it the right way to use `get_data($post);`

Curl info gives :

I get this :

```
array(20) { 
["url"]=> string(68) "http://secret-url.com" 
["content_type"]=> string(9) "text/html" 
["http_code"]=> int(301) 
["header_size"]=> int(255) 
["request_size"]=> int(340) 
["filetime"]=> int(-1) 
["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) 
["redirect_count"]=> int(0) 
["total_time"]=> float(0.095589) 
["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.012224) 
["connect_time"]=> float(0.049399) 
["pretransfer_time"]=> float(6.5E-5) 
["size_upload"]=> float(0) 
["size_download"]=> float(0) 
["speed_download"]=> float(0) 
["speed_upload"]=> float(0) 
["download_content_length"]=> float(0) 
["upload_content_length"]=> float(0) 
["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.095534) 
["redirect_time"]=> float(0) 
}
```

Comment: The problem then is that your variable must be set to null. The function doesn't care if you pass a string, or a variable with a string. It looks like you're code might be fetching an empty line at the end, you should make sure that `rtrim(fgets($urllist))` actually returns a non-empty string.

Comment: `rtrim(fgets($urllist))` returns the a url correctly.

Comment: "But when I pass the url using a variable, it returns nothing." that means that whatever variable you are using is either empty - or the cURL request failed.

Comment: I am sure the variable holds the right string/url. And it is even echod to check if it holds data.

I tried the same string in the `get_data` function and it works. I have no clue whats wrong, and thats why I posted it in SO. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code out.

```
function get_data($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 15;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, random_user_agent());

    // Edit: Follow redirects
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

//Grab HTML
$urllist = fopen("links.txt", "r+");
for ($j = 0; $j <= 50; $j++)
{
    if($post = rtrim(fgets($urllist)))
    {
        echo $post;
        echo get_data($post);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No URL provided!";
    }

    echo "\n<hr>\n";
}
```

Comment: You could simply tell me to check if the variable isnt Null. Well, it isnt. `file_get_contents($post) works just fine. but when I pass it to the function, it doesnt work.

Comment: @Kishor, checking the fgets line is only one change. I just added that to be safe. The other is getting cURL to tell you why your requests are failing.

Comment: Added the output in the question. Please check.

Comment: The cURL HTTP error code `["http_code"]=> int(301)` [is a 301](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301). You also need to use `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` with a limit.

Comment: its the redirect indeed: `    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); `

Comment: is there anyway to find which url it is redirected to?

Answer (score 0):

will `$html = file_get_contents($url);` suffice? As records show, it didnt =)

EDIT to sum up conversation with a legitimate answer;

Change your curl into following, containing the FOLLOWLOCATION directive, optionally constrain curl with MAXREDIRS

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 15;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    // follow Location: newurl.tld - i.e. HTTP 30X status codes
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    // give up follow location if circular after 5 tries
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, random_user_agent());
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    // if in doubt, whats going on, look through info of curl_getinfo($ch);
    // var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
//Grab HTML
$urllist = fopen("links.txt", "r+");
for ($j = 0; $j <= 50; $j++) {
    $post = rtrim(fgets($urllist));
    echo $post;
    $html = get_data($post);
    echo $html;
}
```

Optionally, since it seems like youre doing this more then once, returning to youre links.txt pages - set a cookie-container, which allows for the visits to know you have been there before - and reusing that information on consecutive runs

```
// filehandle, writeable by httpd user:
$cookie_file = "/tmp/cookie/cookie1.txt";
// set request to parse cookies and send them with corresponding host requests
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
// set response cookies to be saved
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
```

Comment: That works just fine. But I need to use Curl on this one.

`file_get_content($post)` works just fine. so the variable is giving the right url to the function in `get_data($url)` What could be wrong then? any idea?

Comment: there's absolutely nothing wrong with your php script, problem must come from something other then the posted code or on your server, run debug with : `$info = curl_getinfo($ch); var_dump($info);` right after your curl_exec();, b4 closing it

Comment: Added the output in the question. Please check.